# LaTex cvsautotabular adjusting table size

Tags: csv, latex, tabular

I'm using csvautotabular to import my .CSV file onto my LaTex file, but one of the column is horizontally too long (words not numbers). Therefore, the table is running beyond the margin. This is the code that I currently have:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\caption{Summary of documents}
\csvautotabular{\commonPath/documents.csv}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

The data table is 3 columns table where the last column is filled with words and I want the text to wrap around. Any suggestions would help and if you could actually write out the revised code that would be great.